# Import JSON data to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have been trying for months to get this to work, but as im not that experienced with PHP i havent had much luck doing this from scratch.

I am trying to import a generated JSON file into MySQL with the below code but keep getting errors, i believe its where the fields from the JSON arent matching with the import data... some of the JSON fields arent provided so each line varies (not sure how to dynamically create that).
Also the SQL is open to injection, not sure how to fix that?

```
<?php
// open mysql connection
$host = "localhost";
$username = "mysql_username";
$password = "mysql_password";
$dbname = "jsonimport";
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname) or die('Error in Connecting: ' . mysqli_error($con));

// use prepare statement for insert query
$st = mysqli_prepare($con, 'INSERT INTO emp(x, y, z, lat, lon, id, color0, color1, color2, color3, color4, color5, tamedAtTime, tamedTime, tribe, tamer, name, baseLevel, health, stamina, oxygen, food, weight, melee, speed, tamed, experience) VALUES (?, ?, ?)');

// bind variables to insert query params
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($st, 'sss', $x, $y, $z, $lat, $lon, $id, $color0, $color1, $color2, $color3, $color4, $color5, $tamedAtTime, $tamedTime, $tribe, $tamer, $name, $baseLevel, $health, $stamina, $oxygen, $food, $weight, $melee, $speed, $tamed, $experience);

// read json file
$filename = 'data.json';
$json = file_get_contents($filename);   

//convert json object to php associative array
$data = json_decode($json, true);

// loop through the array
foreach ($data as $row) {
    // get the dino details
$x = $row['x'];
$y = $row['y'];
$z = $row['z'];
$lat = $row['lat'];
$lon = $row['lon'];
$id = $row['id'];
$color0 = $row['color0'];
$color1 = $row['color1'];
$color2 = $row['color2'];
$color3 = $row['color3'];
$color4 = $row['color4'];
$color5 = $row['color5'];
$tamedAtTime = $row['tamedAtTime'];
$tamedTime = $row['tamedTime'];
$tribe = $row['tribe'];
$tamer = $row['tamer'];
$name = $row['name'];
$baseLevel = $row['baseLevel'];
$health = $row['health'];
$stamina = $row['stamina'];
$oxygen = $row['oxygen'];
$food = $row['food'];
$weight = $row['weight'];
$melee = $row['melee'];
$speed = $row['speed'];
$tamed = $row['tamed'];
$experience = $row['experience'];

    // execute insert query
    mysqli_stmt_execute($st);
}

//close connection
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Import Code:

```
{"x":205686.734375,"y":57330.2734375,"z":-9629.2021484375,"lat":57.2,"lon":75.7,"id":110197191702290902,"tamed":true,"team":1418527958,"female":true,"color0":14,"color4":14,"color5":14,"tamedAtTime":1166123.9561051205,"tamedTime":3275684.0438948795,"tribe":"DattoSSS","name":"Dattoss","imprinter":"Syn","baseLevel":196,"wildLevels":{"health":28,"stamina":29,"oxygen":31,"food":21,"weight":26,"melee":36,"speed":24},"fullLevel":216,"tamedLevels":{"health":5,"melee":15},"experience":14006.5849609375,"imprintingQuality":0.8208027482032776}
```

Also is there a way to parse a whole folder of JSON files and import?
For example each file is ObjectName_Character_BP_C.json is there a way to send the data from each json file to its table witht he same name?
e.g parse Angler_Character_BP_C.json, and them import into jsonimport.Angler_Character_BP_C (mysql table)

please let me know if you need additional data ... im so lost here :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with this below code. Hope it will help you to solve your problem.

```
<?php
function pr($arr)
{
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($arr);
    echo '</pre>';
}

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "mysql_username";
$password = "mysql_password";
$dbname = "jsonimport";
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$json = '{"0":{"x":205686.734375,"y":57330.2734375,"z":-9629.2021484375,"lat":57.2,"lon":75.7,"id":110197191702290902,"tamed":true,"team":1418527958,"female":true,"color0":14,"color4":14,"color5":14,"tamedAtTime":1166123.9561051205,"tamedTime":3275684.0438948795,"tribe":"DattoSSS","name":"Dattoss","imprinter":"Syn","baseLevel":196,"wildLevels":{"health":28,"stamina":29,"oxygen":31,"food":21,"weight":26,"melee":36,"speed":24},"fullLevel":216,"tamedLevels":{"health":5,"melee":15},"experience":14006.5849609375,"imprintingQuality":0.8208027482032776}}';

//convert json object to php associative array
$data = json_decode($json, true);

// prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ptero_character_bp_c (`list_x`, `list_y`, `list_z`, `list_lat`, `list_lon`, `list_id`, `list_tamed`, `list_color0`, `list_color1`, `list_color2`, `list_color3`, `list_color4`, `list_color5`, `list_tamedAtTime`, `list_tamedTime`, `list_tribe`, `list_tamer`,`list_name`, `list_baseLevel`, `list_wildLevels_health`, `list_wildLevels_stamina`, `list_wildLevels_oxygen`, `list_wildLevels_food`, `list_wildLevels_weight`, `list_wildLevels_melee`, `list_wildLevels_speed`, `list_experience` ) VALUES (?, ?, ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?, ?, ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?, ?, ?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("dddddisiiiiiiddsssiiiiiiiid", $x, $y, $z, $lat, $lon, $id, $tamed, $color0, $color1, $color2, $color3, $color4, $color5, $tamedAtTime, $tamedTime, $tribe, $tamer, $name, $baseLevel, $health, $stamina, $oxygen, $food, $weight, $melee, $speed, $experience);

// loop through the array
foreach ($data as $row) {
    // get the dino details
    $x = $row['x'];
    $y = $row['y'];
    $z = $row['z'];
    $lat = $row['lat'];
    $lon = $row['lon'];
    $id = $row['id'];
    $tamed = $row['tamed'];
    $color0 = !empty($row['color0']) ? $row['color0'] : '';
    $color1 = !empty($row['color1']) ? $row['color1'] : '';
    $color2 = !empty($row['color2']) ? $row['color2'] : '';
    $color3 = !empty($row['color3']) ? $row['color3'] : '';
    $color4 = !empty($row['color4']) ? $row['color4'] : '';
    $color5 = !empty($row['color5']) ? $row['color5'] : '';
    $tamedAtTime = $row['tamedAtTime'];
    $tamedTime = $row['tamedTime'];
    $tribe = $row['tribe'];
    $tamer = !empty($row['tamer']) ? $row['tamer'] : '';
    $name = $row['name'];
    $baseLevel = $row['baseLevel'];
    $health = $row['wildLevels']['health'];
    $stamina = $row['wildLevels']['stamina'];
    $oxygen = $row['wildLevels']['oxygen'];
    $food = $row['wildLevels']['food'];
    $weight = $row['wildLevels']['weight'];
    $melee = $row['wildLevels']['melee'];
    $speed = $row['wildLevels']['speed'];
    $experience = $row['experience'];
    // execute insert query
    $stmt->execute();
    echo "New records created successfully";
}

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```

**Code Explanation:**

**`$stmt->bind_param("sss", $x, $y, $z);`**

This function binds the parameters to the SQL query and tells the database what the parameters are. The "sss" argument lists the types of data that the parameters are. The s character tells mysql that the parameter is a string.

The argument may be one of four types:

- i - integer
- d - double
- s - string
- b - BLOB

You must have one of these for each parameter.

By telling mysql what type of data to expect, we minimize the risk of SQL injections.

Comment: Hey Faisal, i tried the code, replaced "emp" with the table name ... but nothing happens, web page is blank and no data is inserted into the table

Comment: My code is tested in local machine.can please show me your database schema?

Comment: cant paste the code here, check out pastebin - http://pastebin.com/YV7m46ic

Comment: as per your db schema you need to change this line like `$stmt->bind_param("ddd", $x, $y, $z);`

Comment: so with your example `$stmt->bind_param("ddd", $x, $y, $z);` i would actually need to do ? 
`$stmt->bind_param("sss", $x, $y, $z, $lat, $lon, $id, $color0, $color1, $color2, $color3, $color4, $color5, $tamedAtTime, $tamedTime, $tribe, $tamer, $name, $baseLevel, $health, $stamina, $oxygen, $food, $weight, $melee, $speed, $tamed, $experience);`

Comment: @simon i am updating my answer just now. Please check this new update. hope it should work for you. i have test this code in my local machine.

Comment: thanks, that code works, i never would have got the additions you made, you're a champ

Answer (score 0):

You need one '?' in the prepare statement for each variable in the bind statement. You have only 3 '?', so it won't work the way it is.

Try simpler experiments with 2 or 3 variables to see how it works. Then expand when you get it. You probably need 'd' in the bind for doubles, not 's' for string.
 eg;

```
  $st = mysqli_prepare($con, 'INSERT INTO emp (x, y, z) values (?, ? , ?);
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($st, 'ddd', $x, $y, $z);
```

You can also use variable names in the prepare statement for the table name, so you can import data from different files and set the table name as needed.